# Union of simply connected set is simply connect implies intersection is simply connected

Tags: general-topology

Let $U$ and $V$ be two simply connected subsets in an arbitrary topological space. They are either both open or both closed. If $U\cup V$ is simply connected, does it imply $U\cap V$ is simply connected?

On $\mathbb{R}^2$ I can come up with an example when $U\cap V$ is not simply connected, but all my examples shows $U\cup V$ has to contain some "holes".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**: Consider the sphere $S^2$ instead of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

> **Solution**: Take two disks, one covering the north pole and one covering the south pole, intersecting in a ring around the equator. The disks are simply connected, their union is simply connected, but their intersection deformation retracts to a circle.